# Can't npm install firebase

Tags: firebase, npm

I'm trying to do npm install for firebase but I keep running into errors...
I tried with npm version 5.6.0 and 5.7.1
I even tried installing assert-plus but that also failed (similar error to below). Any suggestions?

```
vagrant [polaris]> npm install firebase
npm ERR! path /vagrant/polaris/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/dashdash/node_modules/assert-plus/package.json.2882240414
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/vagrant/polaris/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/dashdash/node_modules/assert-plus/package.json.2882240414'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2018-03-14T23_28_13_938Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `npm install -g firebase-tools` instead of `npm install -g firebase`. After that, you'll be able to initialize your project on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

One quick suggestion. Delete your node_modules folder and do a fresh 'npm install'.